# How to open HTML web resource in modal dialog

Tags: dialog, dynamics-crm-2011

I created some HTML web resource. How can I open it in modal dialog after clicking on some ribbon button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to use http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/ to edit your ribbon. On your button, set the action to url and link to your webresource. In the win mode setting choose Model Dialog.

This is what I have in the address field on the action:

```
http://server/organization/WebResources/new_htmlpage
```

new_htmlpage is the name of the webresource.

Here is the CommandDefinitions part of ribbondiff

```
<CommandDefinitions>
  <CommandDefinition Id="new.Form.account.MainTab.ExportData.modalPopup.Command">
    <EnableRules />
    <DisplayRules />
    <Actions>
      <Url WinMode="1" Address="http://server/organization/WebResources/new_htmlpage" PassParams="false" />
    </Actions>
  </CommandDefinition>
</CommandDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the address you should have $webresource:new_htmlpage

This way you have a relative link to the web resource!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about CRM 2011 but in 2015 better not use Url Action to open Html Web Resources, MSDN:

> Don’t use this action(Url Action) to open entity forms or web resources. Use the  (RibbonDiffXml) with a function that uses Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm or Xrm.Utility.openWebResource instead.

Also with Url Action you can't simply send query string parameters to Html Web Resource and parameters must be encoded in "data" query string parameter.

```
var customParameters = encodeURIComponent("first=First Value&second=SecondValue&third=Third Value");
Xrm.Utility.openWebResource("new_webResource.htm",customParameters);
```

MSDN:
[Xrm.Utility (client-side reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72a66f93-92df-42b9-a8fd-b6125c7fe83b(v=crm.7)#BKMK_OpenWebResource)