# window.open a silverlight from CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, html, silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

i have a button in CRM 2011. If i click it, a .html webresource will be opened. This .html page is hosting a silverlight application.

All the stuff works very well if i open the site from my server.
But if i open the site from a client, the .html site dont show up.

i open the .html window with

```
window.open("hereIsMyUrl");
```

Now it should open the .html site, but it dont show up. 
I captured the network, and there are some requests from my silverlight.
[image]

So the .html site is loaded and my silverlight code is running, but there is now window which popped up.

Sometimes i can see the window, i think everytime i close IE and open it again.

Thank for your help
Alex

Edit:
I forgot to tell you, that my CRM system is protected with claime based authentication (https)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it wasn't a programming issue. In the background there were some IE instances opened. I killed these processes and now I don't have any issues on client side.

Answer (score 2):

i don't know which rollup you have but xrm.utility appear in rollup 8, but i have two options i don't know if gonna resolve your problem but it's a better supported way to open a WebResource:

- [Xrm.Utility.openWebResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72a66f93-92df-42b9-a8fd-b6125c7fe83b#BKMK_OpenWebResource)
- In [ribbon button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380281/how-to-open-html-web-resource-in-modal-dialog)

Comment: Thanks Predro, i am using update rollup 12. I will try Xrm.Utility.openWebResource tomorrow. But i think inside this function the page will also be called with window.open(). But i will give it a try. Thanks